# CloudKit's subscriptions not working

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, subscriptions

I'm trying to send a notification whenever a user creates a new Event in my app. I could set up successfully the notification, because I can see it in my cloud kit dashboard, but when someone creates an Event, nothing happens...

The thing is: In ViewController1, the user select the name and the participants of the event, and in ViewController2 he continues selecting some other stuff. What I wanna say is that I don't need to upload any visual details in my app (when the notification arrives), I only want that when the notification shows up, the user goes DIRECTLY to ViewController2. Here is my code:

**App Delegate:**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)

    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    let cloudKitNotification = CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary: userInfo as! [String : NSObject])

    if cloudKitNotification.notificationType == CKNotificationType.Query {


        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("notinoti", object: nil)

    }
}
```

**ViewController1:**

```
func setupCloudKitSubscription() {

    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if userDefaults.boolForKey("subscribed") == false {

        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil)
        let subscription = CKSubscription(recordType: "Event", predicate: predicate, options: CKSubscriptionOptions.FiresOnRecordCreation)

        let notificationInfo = CKNotificationInfo()
        notificationInfo.alertLocalizationKey = "New event"
        notificationInfo.shouldBadge = true
        notificationInfo.desiredKeys = ["name"]

        subscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo

        let publicData = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
        publicData.saveSubscription(subscription, completionHandler: { (subscription, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                userDefaults.setBool(true, forKey: "subscribed")
                userDefaults.synchronize()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**ViewController2:**

```
var currentRecord: CKRecord?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self , selector: Selector("fetchRecord"), name: "notinoti", object: nil)
    })
}

func fetchRecord(recordID: CKRecordID) -> Void {

    let publicDatabase = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase

    publicDatabase.fetchRecordWithID(recordID, completionHandler: ({record, error in
        if let err = error {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                print(err.localizedDescription)
            }
        } else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.currentRecord = record
                //Now do something with the data
            }
        }
    }))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pedro,

Don't know if its significant but my "working" subscription line reads. I got a subscriptionID in my code?

```
  let subID = String(NSUUID().UUIDString)
  let predicateY = NSPredicate(value: true)
  let subscription = CKSubscription(recordType: "Blah", predicate: predicateY, subscriptionID: subID, options: [.FiresOnRecordUpdate, .FiresOnRecordDeletion])
```

I got a vague recollection of it not working after a while of fooling round with it, at which point I reset the db on the cloud kit dashboard and resubscribed, and it worked again.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help! So, you suggest that I only reset the dashboard and should work??

Comment: Yes, maybe that will fix it; note my subscription line includes an subscription ID too, your using a slightly simpler call.

Comment: I tried resetting the dashboard, but still not working... I'll redo the code using a subs ID now. Thanks!